# Need help placing LIMIT,OFFSET in this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset

This query returns forum questions/answers and their nested comments (similar to the StackOverflow paradigm).

```
    SELECT forum_qa.*,
           user_profiles.*,
           c.*,
           n.pid,
           v.*,
           Ifnull(n.ans_count, 0) AS ans_count
    FROM   forum_qa
           JOIN user_profiles
             ON user_id = forum_qa_author_id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                      FROM   votes) AS v
             ON forum_qa_id = v.forum_qa_id_fk
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT forum_cm_id,
                             forum_cm_author_id,
                             forum_qa_id_fk,
                             forum_cm_text,
                             forum_cm_timestamp,
                             forum_cm_flag,
                             first_name  AS forum_cm_first_name,
                             last_name   AS forum_cm_last_name,
                             facebook_id AS forum_cm_fb_id,
                             picture     AS forum_cm_picture,
                             moderator   AS forum_cm_moderator
                      FROM   forum_cm
                             JOIN user_profiles
                               ON user_id = forum_cm_author_id) AS c
             ON forum_qa_id = c.forum_qa_id_fk
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT forum_qa_parent_id AS pid,
                             COUNT(*)           AS ans_count
                      FROM   forum_qa
                      WHERE  forum_qa_parent_id IS NOT NULL
                      GROUP  BY forum_qa_parent_id) AS n
             ON forum_qa_id = n.pid
    WHERE  forum_qa_id LIKE "%"
           AND forum_qa_parent_id IS NULL
    ORDER  BY forum_qa_timestamp DESC
            LIMIT  0,3
```

I am trying to paginate the results and am hitting the following problem:

By placing LIMIT at the end of the query, I end up limiting the number of ***total*** rows, not the number of questions/answers.

For ex, `LIMIT 0,3` in the last line gives me (qa: question/answer; cm: comment):

```
forum_qa_id   qa_text   forum_cm_id    cm_text
1             asd
2             wer       4              this is a comment
2             wer       5              this is another comment
```

instead of

```
forum_qa_id   qa_text   forum_cm_id    cm_text
1             asd
2             wer       4              this is a comment
2             wer       5              this is another comment
3             zxc       
3             zxc       7              yet another comment
```

Any suggestions how to modify my query in order to have `LIMIT 0,3` return ***not 3 rows*** but 3 questions regardless of how many nested comments is has?

**changes with @michael's suggestion**

```
    SELECT qa.*,
           user_profiles.*,
           c.*,
           n.pid,
           v.*,
           Ifnull(n.ans_count, 0) AS ans_count
    FROM   (SELECT * FROM forum_qa LIMIT 0, 3) qa
           JOIN user_profiles
             ON user_id = qa.forum_qa_author_id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                      FROM   votes) AS v
             ON qa.forum_qa_id = v.forum_qa_id_fk
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT forum_cm_id,
                             forum_cm_author_id,
                             forum_qa_id_fk,
                             forum_cm_text,
                             forum_cm_timestamp,
                             forum_cm_flag,
                             first_name  AS forum_cm_first_name,
                             last_name   AS forum_cm_last_name,
                             facebook_id AS forum_cm_fb_id,
                             picture     AS forum_cm_picture,
                             moderator   AS forum_cm_moderator
                      FROM   forum_cm
                             JOIN user_profiles
                               ON user_id = forum_cm_author_id) AS c
             ON qa.forum_qa_id = c.forum_qa_id_fk
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT forum_qa_parent_id AS pid,
                             COUNT(*)           AS ans_count
                      FROM   forum_qa
                      WHERE  forum_qa_parent_id IS NOT NULL
                      GROUP  BY forum_qa_parent_id) AS n
             ON qa.forum_qa_id = n.pid
    WHERE  qa.forum_qa_id LIKE "%"
           AND qa.forum_qa_parent_id IS NULL
    ORDER  BY qa.forum_qa_timestamp DESC
```

**(HOPEFULLY) THE SOLUTION**

After reading here

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

I decided to index the field I wanted to `ORDER BY` (forum_qa_type) -- once I did this, the query is returning the correct number of questions.

Thanks @Michael for helping out. Will update here if this stops working.

Comment: Just noticed you edited this.  How many rows to you get with only the single join against `user_profiles`?

Comment: hey michael take a look at the new info I put under "short version". this is mind boggling.

Comment: put an explicit `ORDER BY` in the `qa` subquery:  `ORDER BY something LIMIT 0,3`

Comment: that returns 2 questions

Comment: And form_qa_author_id is never NULL?  Also, get that `LIKE '%'` out of there for debugging.

Comment: OK - if I ORBER BY forum_qa_timestamp (INT), then I get 2 questions -- but if I ORDER BY forum_qa_type (TINY INT) then I get 3 questions

Comment: I can't really make sense of that :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `forum_qa` is the table holding the questions, you can place its `SELECT *` into a subquery with its own limit. This is of course untested, but should work in principle.

```
SELECT     qa.*,
           user_profiles.*,
           c.*,
           n.pid,
           v.*,
           Ifnull(n.ans_count, 0) AS ans_count
    FROM   (SELECT * FROM forum_qa LIMIT 0, 3) qa 
          JOIN user_profiles
             ON user_profiles.user_id = qa.forum_qa_author_id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT *.....
           -- etc...
```

Additional references to the table name `forum_qa` will need to be changed to its new alias `qa`.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but I think I'm screwing up somewhere -- I posted the updated code in OP -- it still returns 3 rows instead of 3 questions -- any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @torr I can't see any other problems - you have `LEFT JOIN`s where appropriate. I would suggest removing other joined tables/subqueries and progressively adding them back to debug